# How to pull data from Starting month of year to the given month based on the month parameter value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

IF I Select @rpmMonth = SEP 2019 it should pull the data from JAN 2019 to SEP 2019
**I Have only One Parameter Value i.e @rpmMonth of VARCHAR Type.

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @firstDay Date=(
select convert(varchar(10),DATEADD(Year,-1*DateDiff(Year,getdate(),0),0),120))

Declare @CurDate Date=(
SELECT convert(varchar(10),DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())+1,0)),120))

select * from YOURTABLE
where colname between @firstDay  and @CurDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should be using a `date` datatype, not a `varchar`. If we *do*, however, have to use a `varchar` then you could do something like this:

```
SELECT {Columns}
FROM {Your Schema And Table}
WHERE {DateColumn} >= CONVERT(date,CONCAT(RIGHT(@rpmMonth),'0101'))
 AND {DateColumn} < DATEADD(MONTH, 1, CONVERT(date, '01 ' + @rpmMonth));
```

*(Obviously replace the parts in braces (`{}`) and **assumes** the language of the `LOGIN` is an English based language.)*

This would give you all rows on or after Jan 01 of the year for `@rpmMonth` and **before** the month after `@rpmMonth`.

If you use a proper date, and pass the first date of the month i.e. (`2019-09-01` for the sample you gave), then you could do the below:

```
SELECT {Columns}
FROM {Your Schema And Table}
WHERE {DateColumn} >= DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, @rpmMonth),0)
  AND {DateColumn} < DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @rpmMonth);
```

Comment: Dear Lamu, In the line CONVERT(date,CONCAT(RIGHT(@rpmMonth),'0101') It is throwing some arguments error !

Comment: Missing a right parenthesis, @Lookup . (P.s. "Some arguments error" isn't helpful; if you get an error, tell us the error.)

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server is pretty good about converting date values.  You should be able to do:

```
select . . .
from t cross join
     (values (convert(date, @rpmMonth)) as v(dte)
where datecol >= datefromparts(year(v.dte), 1, 1) and
      datecol < datefromparts(year(dateadd(month, 1, v.dte)), month(dateadd(month, 1, v.dte)), 1)
```